# Questions on iostream and initializer_list

Tags: c++

I have received the following error for the following code on Visual Studio Code for Mac.

```
ArrayStudy.cpp:21:19: error: cannot deduce type of initializer list because std::initializer_list was not found; include <initializer_list>
    for (auto x : {10,21,32,43,54,65})
```

I included `#include <initializer_list>` after noting it was absent, but continued to receive the error. I'm using Apple clang version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30).

At this point I am stumped.  Can someone help me get this code running with a short explanation of what I missed?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <initializer_list>

void print();

int main(){

    print();

}

void print() {
    int v[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

    for (auto x : v)
        cout << x << '\n';

    for (auto x : {10,21,32,43,54,65})
        cout << x << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Which compiler and compiler version are you using and with what flags are you invoking the compiler? "_and continued to receive the error._": Make sure you actually compiled the modified file and didn't accidentally compile an old version e.g. because you didn't save the file.

Comment: Why is your `using` statement in the middle of your headers, instead of after them? For that matter, [why are you using that `using` statement in the first place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)?

Comment: Apple clang version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30).  I did not compile an old version of the file.  I removed the using statement as well.

Comment: What options are you passing to the compiler? Use something like `-std=c++20` or similar, but at least `-std=c++11`. This is a C++11 feature.

Comment: Please add all relevant information as an [edit] to the question, instead of as comments. I've added the compiler details from your comment, but please add the compiler flags that you're using, as has already been requested.

Comment: How do you run the -std=c++11 command on the Visual Studio code terminal?  Is the terminal where this command is run?  How ill this help me with the question above?

Comment: I also wondered if there is an error in the second for statement "where every element of the array places a copy in x".  Is that the correct logic for this line of code?